# Azure Data Factory - ARM Template

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying ARM template to Azure Data Factory v2 using PowerShell command

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyDeployment -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -TemplateFile C:\work\arm_template.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\work\arm_template_parameters.json
```

There are two Oracle 12c Linked Services in the factory. The deployment fails with error messages pointing something wrong was with these linked services. The messages provide no details:

```
Resource Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices 'myDataFactory/myLinkedServiceOne' failed with message '{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Error message not found.
```

I can see all resources of the Data Factory in Azure Cloud after the deployment fails but those two Linked Services (and pipelines that depend on the Linked Services)

The issue I'm aware of is I didn't know how connection strings should have look like. I didn't find it in MS documentation so I made them up completely. They were as follows (arm-template-parameters.json):

```
    "myLinkedServiceOne_connectionString": {
        "value": "Host=mydatabase.host.net;Port=1536;SID=someSid;User Id=someUser;Password=somePassword;"
    },
```

My question is: How Oracle DB connection string should look like in ARM parameters file?

Comment: Are you using Oracle connector or ODBC connector with Oracle driver? Is your arm template configure file exported from UI?

Comment: Did the test connection pass in UI if you are using UI to generate these ARM template files.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your Integration Runtime is offline. Please restart it and try it again.

You connection string looks fine according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#linked-service-properties).

But if you are using ODBC connector, you should follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc#linked-service-properties).